# Android: Disable mandatory restart when changing SIM-cards

Tags: android, sim-card

For an app that I am currently developing we want to read data from the SIM card of the user, which works fine. We want to make it possible that the user can switch the SIM card while the app is running. While doing this the OS request a device restart and we cannot seem to suppress this message.

Is there a way to make it able to insert a SIM card while the app is running without restarting the device. I'm open for all options (rooting, custom rom, etc...)

Comment: What sort of devices are you dealing with? Every phone I have requires me to remove the battery before I can even remove the SIM card and insert a new one.

Comment: We are developing on a Samsung Note 10.1, which has an easy accessible SIM card slot (and is our target device). We also tested on Nexus 5. Same results on both devices.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible - I never saw any option in phone settings allowing to turn on or off this feature. What might interest you is that for some phones - for example Sony Xperia Z as far as I remember - phone allowed changing SIM card without restart.

Comment: I have seen it working on HTC One, this device does not require a restart when swapping SIM and if I understand your answer correctly you have seen the same behavior on the Sony Xperia Z. I'm curious what makes these devices different in software or hardware...

Comment: I've eddited mine (previously cropped) answer. Looks that's just another inconstency between Android phone models

Answer (score 0):

I found a method but i don't know if it'll work with other devices.

```
Device:Sony E4g(2003)
Android:4.4.4
Root required :yes
Apps Needed :Romtoolbox pro
```

First open rom toolbox and go to app manager, then search for `"Sim Detection"` it is a system app, then click it and go to `"advanced freeze option"` then You Disable `"SimDetectionReciever"` and you're Done.

Hope this helps